# Error HTTP Error 403: SSL is required when pip installing MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, django, server

I'm having a problem pip installing MySQL Python on my server.

Full stack trace is as follows:

```
(ENV)[fendyhj@web530 lepaperville]$ pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/home/fendyhj/webapps/lepaperville/ENV/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 194, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Downloading 
http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Anyone know how to install MySQL Python through HTTPS ?
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a really old version of pip installed (check with `pip --version`). Note that `MySQL-python` hasn't been updated [since 2014](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5). Are you sure you want to install that, and not the fork `mysqlclient`?

Comment: @Alasdair pip version is 1.3.1, I'll try with mysqlclient then, maybe it is outdated

Comment: That's a really old version of pip - that could be what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is finally to install mysqlclient instead, as MySQL Python hasn't been updated since 2014, credit to @alasdair

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python is missing the ssl bindings, I would make sure ssl is installed and reinstall python. If it does not work you can compile python yourself https://askubuntu.com/questions/21547/what-are-the-packages-libraries-i-should-install-before-compiling-python-from-so

Answer (score 0):

you can get `tar` package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/, and install it manually